# Android start activity when user enters value in edit text

Tags: android, textfield

I noticed that apps like google maps and lyft have a feature/behavior that when the user starts typing an address into a textfield, the text field takes the entire screen (starts a new activity) with a specific focus on the input. When the user selects something from the listview, they are taking back to the screen with all the other info

I'm just curious as to how something like that could be achieved.
Are they using a different activity?

[image]

The app that I am working on has a similar feature but I guess am not sure how to get my textfield to cover the entire screen (or perhaps start a different activity) when user starts typing.

I am just looking for a pointer or an example. Unfortunately because I don't know the exact name of what I am looking it makes searching for it in the docs a bit hard. Any pointers would be appreciated!

**PS:** I am aware of this approach but that is not what I am looking for

`<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode=""/>`

Comment: I would think this is a good place to use fragments instead of starting a new activity. Also, see if this helps: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: You can even use Dialog in full screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way that I ended up doing was starting an activity for result once the textfield got activated and the setting the value once the new completed

Answer (score 0):

What I would actually do is: I would create it as a "simple" view. Not a fragment, not an activity.

- I would start by creating a layout that would represent the
  "expanded" version of your TextView (I will distinguish between *expanded* and *collapsed* states of the view; expanded is the state when it fills the entire screen).
- I would set its width and height to `match_parent` and I would place 
  it inside the activity (or fragment or whatever). Anchoring it with `align_parentTop` for example.
- Set `clipChildren` on the main activity's layout to `false`
- Inside this `Activity` `onCreate` (or similar place in some other
  sort of container), I would add something more less like this:

code:

```
mExpandableTextView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.expandable_text_view_layout);
    //layout representing the expandable textview (defined in expanded state)

mExpandableTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int width = mExpandableTextView.getWidth();
        int height = mExpandableTextView.getHeight();
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            mExpandableTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            // setting the height and width of the view to fixed values (instead of match_parent)
            // this problably is not really necessary but I will write it just to be sure it works as intended
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mExpandableTextView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height;
            params.width = width;
            mExpandableTextView.setLayoutParams(params);

            mMaxTranslationY = height - mCollapsedHeight;
                //mCollapsedHeight is the height of the view in collapsed state
                //provide it in most convenient way for you

            mExpandableTextView.setTranslationY(mMaxTranslationY);
                //setting it to the collapsed state when activity is being displayed for the first time
        }
    }
});
```

(Remember to use `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()` if your app is for devices `< API16`)

- Then I would detect clicks at the only visible part of our view (layout) when in collapsed state, and I would use the following code to expand it or collapse it:

collapse:

```
mExpandableTextView.animate().translationY(mMaxTranslationY); //to collapse with animation
```

expand:

```
mExpandableTextView.animate().translationY(0); //to expand with animation
```